# P-value correction in R: what is the parameter "n" used for and when should I use it?

Tags: r, p-value

The function `p.adjust()` in R accepts a parameter `n` that defaults to the
length of the vector of p-values one wants to adjust:

`p.adjust(p, method = p.adjust.methods, n = length(p))`

In the documentation the explanation for `n` says:

> n  number of comparisons, must be at least length(p); only set this
>   (to non-default) when you know what you are doing!

What does this mean? When could it be helpful to set it to a value different from the default?

Answer (score 1):

See later in the help where it says:

> Note that you can set n larger than length(p) which means the
>   unobserved p-values are assumed to be greater than all the observed p
>   for "bonferroni" and "holm" methods and equal to 1 for the other
>   methods.

I can't think, offhand, of a case where you would want to do this, but perhaps if you have a great many p-values, and you are only interested in corrected values for some of them, this saves some typing.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, unfortunately it still is not very clear to me what would mean assuming that the p-values are higher than all the observed ones. How would this affect the correction?

Comment: If you had more p-values than you listed, then, e.g. for Bonferroni, you would divide by n, not length(p). You have to assume these are greater than those you do list because otherwise, some of them might be significant (in Bonferroni at least). But for details you'd have to look at the methods papers. Basically, you're fine if you never use this option!

Comment: I just have this doubt. Say that I have 10.000 p-values in a vector p.
I decide that my confidence is the classical 0.05.
Should I adjust the correction to all the p-values in p or only to those that are below 0.05? In this second case, should I use the n value?